# FillConsoleOutputCharacterW() C++ error

Tags: c++, windows

I'm getting a runtime error whenver this section of code runs:

```
    void PrintChar(int x, int y, char ch, Colors color) {
    COORD c = {y,x};

    FillConsoleOutputCharacterW(GameData::handle, ch, 1, c, NULL);
    FillConsoleOutputAttribute(GameData::handle, color, 1, c, NULL);
}
```

The error is that it is overwriting location 0x00000000

Could someone explain why this error comes up with an example please?

GameData class -

```
class GameData {
public:
static CRITICAL_SECTION cs;
static void * handle;
static GameStates gameState;

static int speed;
static int level;
static int points;
static int nextShape;
static int nextTurnShape;
};
```

Colours -

```
enum Colors {
Black, DarkBlue, Green, Blue, Red, Purple, Yellow, While, Gray,
LightDarkBlue, LightGreen, LightBlue, LightRed, LightPurple, LightYellow, BrightWhile
};
```

P.S.

Please let me know if I need to provide any more code to clarify what is going on.

Comment: Can you please include some code?

Comment: Which parts do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation of that API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682663(v=vs.85).aspx

You should pass the address of a DWORD variable that receives the number of characters actually written to the console screen buffer

```
void PrintChar(int x, int y, char ch, Colors color)
{ 
    DWORD dwNumOfCharsWritten;

    COORD c = {static_cast<short>(y), static_cast<short>(x)};

    FillConsoleOutputCharacterW(GameData::handle, ch, 1, c, &dwNumOfCharsWritten);
    FillConsoleOutputAttribute(GameData::handle, color, 1, c, &dwNumOfCharsWritten);
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to assign a NULL value to dwNumOfCharWritten? How would it affect the output?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you assign any value to that variable cause it will be overwritten by that API. You should use dwNumOfCharsWritten to check for errors